# Merging a data frame from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frame that looks like this:

```
ls[[1]]
[[1]]

 month year   oracle
    1 2004 356.0000
    2 2004 390.0000
    3 2004 394.4286
    4 2004 391.8571 
 ls[[2]]
 [[2]]
 month year microsoft
    1 2004  339.0000
    2 2004  357.7143
    3 2004  347.1429
    4 2004  333.2857
```

How do I create a single data frame that looks like this:

```
 month year   oracle   microsoft
    1 2004 356.0000    339.0000
    2 2004 390.0000    357.7143
    3 2004 394.4286    347.1429
    4 2004 391.8571    333.2857
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could also use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('month', 'year')), lst)
```

Using @Jaap's example, if the values are not the same, use `all=TRUE` option from `merge`.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('month', 'year'), all=TRUE), ls)
#     month year   oracle microsoft   google
#1     1 2004 356.0000        NA       NA
#2     2 2004 390.0000  339.0000       NA
#3     3 2004 394.4286  357.7143 390.0000
#4     4 2004 391.8571  347.1429 391.8571
#5     5 2004       NA  333.2857 357.7143
#6     6 2004       NA        NA 333.2857
```

Comment: You can turn it into a recursive left-join with `all.x=TRUE`. Note that the order of the list now becomes important.

Comment: does the `(...)` need to be filled with a variable name like `x` or should be be left as `(...)` ?

Comment: @thentangler the 3 dots, is a variadic argument, it can take any number of arguments.  Here, `merge` takes only two, so we can change that to `function(x, y) merg(x, y, by = c('month', 'year'), all = TRUE)` as well

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Gives me a clearer understanding now!

Answer (score 5):

Using the `Reduce`/`merge` code from @akrun's answer will work great if the values for the `month` and `year` columns are the same for each dataframe. However, when they are not the same (example data at the end of this answer)

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('month', 'year')), ls)
```

will return only the rows which are common in each dataframe:

```
  month year   oracle microsoft   google
1     3 2004 394.4286  357.7143 390.0000
2     4 2004 391.8571  347.1429 391.8571
```

In that case, you can either use `all=TRUE` (as shown by @akrun) or use  `full_join` from the `dplyr` package as an alternative when you want to include all rows/observations:

```
library(dplyr)
Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by = c('month', 'year')), ls) 
# or just:
Reduce(full_join, ls)
```

this will result in:

```
  month year   oracle microsoft   google
1     1 2004 356.0000        NA       NA
2     2 2004 390.0000  339.0000       NA
3     3 2004 394.4286  357.7143 390.0000
4     4 2004 391.8571  347.1429 391.8571
5     5 2004       NA  333.2857 357.7143
6     6 2004       NA        NA 333.2857
```

---

Used data:

```
ls <- list(structure(list(month = 1:4, year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), oracle = c(356, 390, 394.4286, 391.8571)), .Names = c("month", "year", "oracle"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), 
           structure(list(month = 2:5, year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), microsoft = c(339, 357.7143, 347.1429, 333.2857)), .Names = c("month", "year", "microsoft"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L)),
           structure(list(month = 3:6, year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), google = c(390, 391.8571, 357.7143, 333.2857)), .Names = c("month", "year", "google"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `do.call()` as follows...

`do.call(merge, ls)`

Comment: This would not work if there are more than 2 list elements

Comment: I meant suppose you have 3 list element, it gives error.

Comment: Yeah point taken... will work for above case though